# Validar correos validos en un textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un textarea que me válida una cadena de correos separados por coma, o mejor conocido como CSV. El evento funciona a medias, por que hace lo que deseo pero no como me gustaría.

Al momento de agregar una cadena, si hay 2 correos inválidos seguidos y separados por coma, ignora el segundo y lo toma como un correo válido. Sin embargo, si vuelvo a entrar al textarea y hago el blur, ese correo lo borra, algo que es como debería de ser, pero no al primer blur.

Como nota, esto solo me pasa cuando hay 2 correos inválidos seguidos.

**Cadena de prueba**

```
jijiji, jojojojo, hope@hope.com, faith@faith.com, jeje
```

```js
$("#txtEmailAll").blur(function () {
    var e_stringCorreos = $(this).val();
    e_stringCorreos = e_stringCorreos.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    var m_correos = e_stringCorreos.split(",");
    m_correos.forEach(function (current, index) {
        var e_correo = m_correos[index];
        if ( /(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(e_correo) == false ) {
            m_correos.splice(index, 1);
            console.log('Correo inválido: ' + e_correo);
        }
    });

    var cleanEmails = m_correos.join(", ");
    $(this).val(cleanEmails);
    console.log('Correos válidos: ' + m_correos.join(", "));
});
```

```html
<!-- jijiji, jojojojo, hope@hope.com, faith@faith.com, jeje -->
<textarea id="txtEmailAll"></textarea>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Intenta ponerlo en otro evento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un ejemplo con menos lineas usando [filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

```js
$("#txtEmailAll").blur(function () {
    let e_stringCorreos = $(this).val()
                                 .replace(/\s+/g, '');
    const m_correos = e_stringCorreos.split(",");
    
    correos_validos = m_correos.filter(function(value){
      return /(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(value);
    })
    console.log(correos_validos.join(", "))
});
```

```html
<!-- jijiji, jojojojo, hope@hope.com, faith@faith.com, jeje -->
<textarea id="txtEmailAll"></textarea>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Solo 2 acotaciones a tu código.

1. En el forEach: Ya tienes el texto, no es necesario buscarlo en el
   array y agregar a una variable.
2. En lugar de eliminar porque no agregas a un array los mails correctos?

Tu código quedaría de esta manera:

```js
$("#txtEmailAll").blur(function () {
    var e_stringCorreos = $(this).val();
    e_stringCorreos = e_stringCorreos.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    var m_correos = e_stringCorreos.split(",");
    var all_mails = [];
    m_correos.forEach(function (current, index) {
        if ( /(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(current) !== false ) {
            console.log('Correo válido: ' + current);
            all_mails.push(current);
        } else {
            console.log('Correo inválido: ' + current);
        }
    });

    var cleanEmails = all_mails.join(", ");
    $(this).val(cleanEmails);
    console.log('Correos válidos: ' + all_mails.join(", "));
});
```

```html
<textarea id="txtEmailAll"></textarea>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```